# How to concatenate DATE and TIME to form DATETIME (TIMESTAMP) in a JPA query?

Tags: java, hibernate, datetime, jpa

I have two fields in a database to store Date and Time. The former has its Time part set to zero, and the latter its Date part set to null (i.e. 1970/1/1). God only knows why the original developer did it this way, and I can't change the table. In a JPA query I need to compare a Timestamp to those two fields as if they were one single DateTime field. In SQL Server I'd do something like this:

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(10), Date_Field, 121) + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), Time_Field, 108)) from MyTable
```

Is there any way to concatenate those two fields in a JPA query so that I can compare them to a complete DateTime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And why dont keep it that way, i mean, if you can not change the structure then use the parameters split, you can make it clear if you use JPA query with parameters:
**To make query**

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT o FROM Object o WHERE o.date = :date AND o.time = :time", Object.class)
.setParameter("date", localDateTime.toDate())
.setParameter("time", localDateTime.toTime())
.getResultList();
```

Then in your entiity you just need an extra mehtod wich will generate the value as you want
**When you have the result list tou can access to the value with this bean property**

```
@Transient //Only necesary if you are declaring the annotations at method level, not if they are in the variable
public DateTime getDateTime() {
    return new DateTime();//Build with the values dateTime and time
}
```

About your date problem, other way (loking horribly, i know, but it works) could be:

```
SELECT r FROM Registry r Where
(r.date = :startDate AND r.time >= :startTime)
OR (r.date = :finalDate AND r.time <= :finalTime)
OR (r.date > :startDate AND r.date < :endDate)
```

The good thing in this query is that it is still being filtered in the db, avoiding trasnporting and transforming data in JPA

Comment: I can see what you mean, but the problem is how to select a range of records using date between DateTimes. If I use one where clause for date and anotther for time, I get a different set of records (I'll get all records between time A and B for each day between date X and Y, and not all between X+A and Y+B). I "solved" the problem in a similar fashion to your suggestion: I fetch the records only by date and then apply Time filter on the resulting list (outside the jpa qyery). So +1.

Comment: @RafaelDiasdaSilva i have updated my answer to make the between dates problem